# Bootstrap table border not showing properly in firefox

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap table border not showing properly in Firefox. I have created a table in project but it's not showing properly in Firefox. But Chrome is fine.

[image]

```css
#product-attribute-specs-table th {border-bottom: medium none;border-radius: 0;border-right: medium none;box-shadow: none;color: #333333;display: block;font-size: 100%;font-weight: 600;line-height: 1.42857;text-align: left;    }
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<table id="product-attribute-specs-table" class="data-table table table-striped">
  <tbody>
    <tr even="">
      <th class="label ">Test 1</th>
      <td class="data">Test 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr odd="">
      <th class="label ">Test 1</th>
      <td class="data">Test 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr even="">
      <th class="label ">Test 1</th>
      <td class="data">Test 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr odd="">
      <th class="label ">Test 1</th>
      <td class="data">Test 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr even="">
      <th class="label ">Test 1</th>
      <td class="data">Test 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr odd="">
      <th class="label ">Test 1</th>
      <td class="data">Test 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr even="">
      <th class="label ">Test 1</th>
      <td class="data">Test 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr odd="">
      <th class="label ">Test 1</th>
      <td class="data">Test 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr even="">
      <th class="label ">Test 1</th>
      <td class="data">Test 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr odd="">
      <th class="label ">Test 1</th>
      <td class="data">Test 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr even="">
      <th class="label ">Test 1</th>
      <td class="data">Test 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr odd="">
      <th class="label ">Test 1</th>
      <td class="data">Test 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr even="">
      <th class="label ">Test 1</th>
      <td class="data">Test 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr odd="">
      <th class="label ">Test 1</th>
      <td class="data">Test 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr even="">
      <th class="label ">Test 1</th>
      <td class="data">Test 2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Why using `<th>` and `<td>` in same row? Just to **bold** text? well you can use `strong` or `b` instead. May be this is causing the issue.

Comment: Learn from here. http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_tables.asp

Comment: Can you test this code firefox as well chrome https://jsfiddle.net/cns1p65r/17/ its working perfect and displays same borders.

Comment: Hello  #Rocky Your code is working as well in all browser. can you suggest me how to solved the issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `display: block` to `display: table-cell`.

CSS:

```
#product-attribute-specs-table th {
  border-bottom: medium none;
  border-radius: 0;
  border-right: medium none;
  box-shadow: none;
  color: #333333;
  display: table-cell;
  font-size: 100%;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 1.42857;
  text-align: left;
}
```

I hope this helps you.

Enjoy :)

Comment: Thanks jyoti very useful answer.